# Excel VBA - Combine rows with duplicate values in one cell and merge values in other cells

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

If there is a duplicate value in column A, I'd like column C-E summed, and column B and F to display the first value that appears.

For example:

```
A    B    C    D    E    F
h    4    2    3    1    5
h    3    3    5    3    7
h    4    4    7    5    4
h    1    1    4    1    4
k    9    3    6    2    4
k    5    3    6    2    7
k    4    3    9    2    7
k    9    4    1    1    4
```

Would become:

```
A    B    C    D    E    F
h    4   10   19   10   5
k    9   13   22   7    4
```

This is the code I used when I was given 4 columns and it worked fine. Now the documents I'm editing have 6 columns and I can't get it to work now.

```vb
Sub mergeCategoryValues()
    Dim lngRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lngRow = .Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(1), Header:=xlYes

        Do
            If .Cells(lngRow, 1) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 1) Then
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, 3) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 3) + .Cells(lngRow, 3)
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, 4) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 4) + .Cells(lngRow, 4)
                .Rows(lngRow).Delete
            End If

            lngRow = lngRow - 1
        Loop Until lngRow = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Would anyone be able to help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `.Cells(lngRow - 1, 5) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 5) + .Cells(lngRow, 5)` inside the `If` block

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've tried doing this and for whatever reason the integers in column 5 aren't summing properly anymore.

Comment: Then there might be something different about that column - it's the same approach that works for columns 3 and 4.  Did you add the line before the `Delete`?

Comment: Yes, I added the line. I'm using this macro on a fairly large spreadsheet ~3000 rows, manually adding the first set of duplicates in column F which add up to about $170,000. When I use this macro on this sheet, I'm getting an extremely inflated number around $800,000,000. I tested this macro on smaller sheets and it's worked fine, but on this larger sheet I can't seem to figure it out. Formatting seems proper too.

Comment: Code looks OK to me, so without some sample data which shows the problem it's difficult to make a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Note where I added two new statements to sum your two add'l columns in the code below, i.e.:

```
.Cells(lngRow - 1, 5) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 5) + .Cells(lngRow, 5)
.Cells(lngRow - 1, 6) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 6) + .Cells(lngRow, 6)
```

Essentially the code you provided is starting at the *last* row of your worksheet and working its way up, row-by-row, adding the values for the current row to the row right above it if the values in column 1 match.  The `5` and `6` lines I added refer to the column numbers that will be aggregated.

```
Sub mergeCategoryValues()
Dim lngRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    lngRow = .Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(1), Header:=xlYes

    Do
        If .Cells(lngRow, 1) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 1) Then
            .Cells(lngRow - 1, 3) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 3) + .Cells(lngRow, 3)
            .Cells(lngRow - 1, 4) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 4) + .Cells(lngRow, 4)

            ' added the next two statements for your new columns
            .Cells(lngRow - 1, 5) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 5) + .Cells(lngRow, 5)
            .Cells(lngRow - 1, 6) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 6) + .Cells(lngRow, 6)
            .Rows(lngRow).Delete
        End If

        lngRow = lngRow - 1
    Loop Until lngRow = 1
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything looks great except I need a way for column 6 to only display the first value it sees instead of summing. Is there a way to do that? For example, if column A displays SPY, SPY, SPY, and column F displays 3, 2, 5, running the code would result in 1 row displaying SPY in column A and 3 in column F because that's the first value that appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and O365
It's really just a single step of grouping by column A, and doing the correct aggregation on columns B..F.  The third line of the MCode below is where all the magic occurs.

- **note** with either of the below methods, sorting of the data is not required.
- Also, either is easily modified to add/remove columns; and/or to decide for which rows to return either SUM or FIRST entry.

Although you can paste the M Code into the Advanced Editor, I suggest going through the steps of generating it yourself, especially if your columns have different names, or if the values are not integers

- select some cell in the table
- Data / Get&Transform / from Table/Range
- When the PQ Editor opens
- Select column A and `group by`
- Select Advanced

  - Enter a `Sum` aggregation for each column B..F
  - After you have done that

    - Home / Advanced Editor
    - You'll see the Table.Group line has multiple `List.Sum` operations for each of those aggregated columns.

      - Change the List.Sum to List.First for the 2nd and last columns.
      - You can also change the column headers in that same line of code.

**M Code**

```
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"A", type text}, {"B", Int64.Type}, {"C", Int64.Type}, {"D", Int64.Type}, {"E", Int64.Type}, {"F", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"A"}, {{"First B", each List.First([B]), type nullable number}, 
        {"Sum C", each List.Sum([C]), type nullable number}, {"Sum D", each List.Sum([D]), type nullable number},
        {"Sum E", each List.Sum([E]), type nullable number},{"First F", each List.First([F]), type nullable number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

If you **must** use VBA, I suggest collecting the data for each item in column A into a dictionary, where the dictionary entry is another dictionary that sums the values for each column (except for the first and last column, where only the first value is retained).

Note that we work in a VBA array as it is usually an order of magnitude faster than working to/from the worksheet.

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (preferable)
'or convert to late binding
Option Explicit
Sub mergeCategoryValues()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim Da As Dictionary, Dv As Dictionary
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, sKeyA As String
    Dim v, w
    
'set the Source and results worksheets, ranges
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet6")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet6")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(12, 16)
    
'read source data into vba array for faster processing
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=6)
End With

'read the values into dictionaries
'each dictionary of col a will contain dictionary with the other column values, either summed or just first
Set Da = New Dictionary
    Da.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1) 'skip the header row
    sKeyA = vSrc(I, 1)
    
    'initial set up for column A ID
    If Not Da.Exists(sKeyA) Then
        Set Dv = New Dictionary
            Dv.CompareMode = TextCompare
        For J = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
            Dv.Add Key:=vSrc(1, J), Item:=vSrc(I, J)
        Next J
        
        Da.Add Key:=sKeyA, Item:=Dv
        
    Else  'Column A entry already exists
        'we just add the value from  column C..next to last column
        '  leaving the first entry in columns A and the last column
        For J = 3 To UBound(vSrc, 2) - 1
            Da(sKeyA)(vSrc(1, J)) = Da(sKeyA)(vSrc(1, J)) + vSrc(I, J)
        Next J
    End If
Next I

'can sort the Da keys if necessary
'create results array
ReDim vRes(0 To Da.Count, 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))

'Headers
For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
    vRes(0, J) = vSrc(1, J)
Next J

'Data
I = 0
For Each v In Da.Keys
    I = I + 1
    vRes(I, 1) = v
    J = 1
    For Each w In Da(v)
        J = J + 1
        vRes(I, J) = Da(v)(w)
    Next w
Next v

'write to the worksheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Style = "Output" 'can change or ignore this, especially if non-english version
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
     
End Sub
```

[image]